# How can I set Jenkins build description while triggering build via curl?

Tags: curl, jenkins, jenkins-cli

I'm trying to set the build description of a build I'm triggering, as I'm kicking off the build, and I have no luck so far.

I came across a solution ([Adding text to the page of a build triggered by the Jenkins remote API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235943/adding-text-to-the-page-of-a-build-triggered-by-the-jenkins-remote-api)), and I kind of got it to work this way (first command will kick off the build, second one will set the description of the last build):

```
curl -v -X POST "http://[myServer]/job/[jobName]/build"
curl -v -X POST "http://[myServer]/job/[jobName/lastBuild/submitDescription" --data-urlencode "description=test description"
```

However, the problem is that if the build I just kicked off gets queued / doesn't kick of right away, "lastBuild" will not reference the build I just kicked off, but the one before it (that is still building).

So I tried something like this:

```
payload='json={""description"":""test description""}'
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d $payload "http://[myServer]/job/[jobName]/build"
```

But it doesn't actually set the description.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Other solutions I found, but I'm not really happy with:

- [Changing Jenkins Build Name & Description through API in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427622/changing-jenkins-build-name-description-through-api-in-java) - that's also a "post trigger solution" that won't work reliably same as just setting the description after
- [Modifying Jenkins Description for a build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839258/modifying-jenkins-description-for-a-build) - I guess I could build in a check, and only modify the description when it's empty so I don't override it, but that seems rather complicated. I'm thinking there must be an easier solution to this, no?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can always have a variable and pass the build description into the variable on the initial invocation. Then at the end of your build, output the variable to console and catch with **[Description Setter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin)**.

**Edit to clarify:**

- Install **[Description Setter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin)**.
- In the Job Configuration, configure a String parameter, call it "**MyDescription**", leave defaults blank.
- Somewhere in the build steps, either "**Execute Shell**" or "**Execute Windows Batch Command**" type `echo Desc: $MyDescription` or `echo Desc: %MyDescription%`, depending on your OS.
- In the Post-Build steps, select "**Set Build Description**".

  - Set *Regular expression* as `^Desc: (.*)`
  - Set *Description* as `\1`
- From command line trigger by:

`curl -v -X POST --data-urlencode "MyDescription=This is my desc" "http://[myServer]/job/[jobName]/buildWithParameters"`
(that above is one line)

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow ... can you please elaborate on: "You can always have a variable and pass the build description into the variable on the initial invocation"? How would I do that? Just to clarify: The build description needs to be different on every triggered build.

Comment: @mac clarified in answer

Comment: That worked, thanks! Though I must say that I figured out a way how to "properly" use the "cause" parameter when triggering the remote build so now I'm just using that instead of the description (the cause can also contain a http link, so does that the trick for me)

Comment: @mac interesting alternative

Answer (score 3):

I had the same need - set the build description **as soon as the build starts**.
Note that the **Build Description Setter** plugin is activated as a *post-build action* which is too late for me.
 
The way I solved it is by a minor change to the job configuration and a Python script (but can be in any language):

- Add a UUID parameter in the job configuration
- Created a script to submit & set description

The script does as follows:

1. When submitting a build, generate a uuid value (unique, right?) and populate the UUID parameter
2. Poll the Jenkins job (get its JSON via REST API), loop on all the running builds, find mine (via the known value of UUID). Limit the polling by a timeout, so we don't hang forever
3. Use the Jenkins Java CLI to set the description (command '**set-build-description**')

Works all the time, except when the build is queued (no free executors are available) and the timeout set above expires - there's nothing I can do.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in using the Jenkins UI, I'm trying:

1. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin
2. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin

The Postbuild plugin is much more powerful, but requires Groovy tinkering and perms.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, with "Execute Groovy System script" :

```
def currentBuild = Thread.currentThread().executable
def FOO = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve('FOO')
currentBuild.setDescription(FOO)
```

Answer (score -4):

**my download:**

```
String urlDownload = "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/ex4clsfmiu142dy/test.zip?token_hash=AAGD-XcBL8C3flflkmxjbzdr7_2W_i6CZ_3rM5zQpUCYaw&dl=1";     
DownloadManager.Request request = new  DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(urlDownload)); 
request.setDescription("Testando"); request.setTitle("Download"); 
request.allowScanningByMediaScanner(); 
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); 
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "teste.zip"); 
final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE); 
final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request); 
final ProgressBar mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1); 

new Thread(new Runnable() { 

    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        boolean downloading = true; 
        while (downloading) { 
            DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query(); 
            q.setFilterById(downloadId); 
            Cursor cursor = manager.query(q); 
            cursor.moveToFirst(); 
            int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR)); 
            int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES)); 
            if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) { 
                downloading = false; 
            } 
            final double dl_progress = (bytes_downloaded / bytes_total) * 100; 
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
                @Override 
                public void run() {
                    mProgressBar.setProgress((int) dl_progress); 
                } 
            }); 
            Log.d(Constants.MAIN_VIEW_ACTIVITY, statusMessage(cursor)); 
            cursor.close(); 
        } 
    } 
}).start();
```

**my statusMessage method:**

```
private String statusMessage(Cursor c) { 
    String msg = "???"; 
    switch (c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS))) { 
        case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED: 
            msg = "Download failed!"; 
            break; 
        case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED: 
            msg = "Download paused!"; 
            break; 
       case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING: 
            msg = "Download pending!"; 
            break; 
       case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING: 
            msg = "Download in progress!"; 
            break; 
       case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL: 
            msg = "Download complete!"; 
            break; 
       default: 
            msg = "Download is nowhere in sight"; 
            break; 
   } 
   return (msg); 
}
```